# Get number of elements in a sorted array that fall within a certain range in log(n) time

Tags: java, algorithm, search, big-o

Say I have an array of the following class sorted in ascending order by y:

```
public class Obj {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

How can I find the number of Obj items in the array that have y values within the min and max range given in log (N) time?

I've thought about using binary search to find the locations of the min and max elements with binarySearch and subtracting, but wouldn't that be 2 log (n) since it's searching twice?

```
public static int getNumberOfItems(Obj[] a, int min, int max) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're asked to do something in `log(n)` time, this usually means `O(log(n))`.

If that's the case here, it is worth noting that `O(2 log(n)) == O(log(n))`, i.e. the two are the same thing.

For further background on the big-oh notation, see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1):

bin search is fine for that approach, O(log N) means c * log N. 
So bin search is fine, but you could optimize bin search call for maxIndex searchimg by  searchomg in range (minFoundIndex, N).

Answer (score 0):

This question is same to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292280/how-to-find-number-of-integers-in-a-sorted-array-that-are-within-a-certain-range), where I gave the **O(logn)** implementation.

The idea is by range binary search for the lower bound and upper bound. For your example, all values are talking about **y** value.

---

1. **For the lower bound (left range)**, you can call the following function to get the index in the sorted array where the value is larger or equal than it, -1 otherwise.

   ```
   int binarySearchForLeftRange(int a[], int length, int left_range)
   {
       if (a[length-1] < left_range)
           return -1;

       int low = 0;
       int high = length-1;

       while (low<=high)
       {
           int mid = low+((high-low)/2);

           if(a[mid] >= left_range)
               high = mid-1;
           else //if(a[mid]<i)
               low = mid+1;
       }

       return high+1;
   }
   ```
2. **For the upper bound (right range)**, you can call the following function to get the index in the sorted array where the value is smaller or equal than it, -1 otherwise.

   ```
   int binarySearchForRightRange(int a[], int length, int right_range)
   {
       if (a[0] > right_range)
           return -1;

       int low = 0;
       int high = length-1;

       while (low<=high)
       {
           int mid = low+((high-low)/2);

           if(a[mid] > right_range)
               high = mid-1;
           else //if(a[mid]<i)
               low = mid+1;
       }

       return low-1;
   }
   ```
3. **Finally**, if you want to get the number of how many elements within this range, it's easy based on return values of these two above functions.

   ```
   int index_left = binarySearchForLeftRange(a, length, left_range);
   int index_right = binarySearchForRightRange(a, length, right_range);

   if (index_left==-1 || index_right==-1 || index_left>index_right)
       count = 0;
   else
       count = index_right-index_left+1;
   ```

---

**Test**: (with duplicates)

```
    int a[] = {1,2,4,4,5,8,12,15,15,23,54};
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int left_range = 4;
    int right_range = 15;
    int index_left = binarySearchForLeftRange(a, length, left_range); // will be 2
    int index_right = binarySearchForRightRange(a, length, right_range); // will be 8

    int count; // will be 7
    if (index_left==-1 || index_right==-1 || index_left>index_right)
        count = 0;
    else
        count = index_right-index_left+1;
```