# Find items in sorted array with properties between a range?

Tags: java, sorting, search

I have an array of class Obj sorted in ascending order based on the age field. I need to find the number of Obj items that have an age within a given min and max age in the array in O(log (N)) time.

I don't think I can use binarySearch because .equals is only true when both name and age are the same.

This is what I've done so far, but I'm not sure what the complexity is.

```
public class Obj {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    private Obj(String name, int age) {
        if (name == null) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Obj)) {
            return false;
        }

        Obj other = (Obj) o;
        return name.equals(other.getName()) && age == other.getAge();
    }

    public static Obj[] loadFromFile(File f) {
        // Loads from file and returns an array of Obj
    }
}

public static int getObjCountInRange(Obj[] a, int minAge, int maxAge) {
    if(a == null || (minAge < 0 || maxAge < 0) || (minAge > maxAge)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i].getAge() >= minAge) {
            start = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    int end = 0;
    for(int i = a.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
        if(a[i].getAge() <= maxAge) {
            end = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (end - start) + 1;
}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: @Aashray I believe OP needs help writing an algorithm that will find values between two points, in a sorted array, in O(Log n) time complexity.

Comment: there's nothing preventing you from looking at the code behing Collections.binarySearch, copying it and modifying it to compare by your field...
all you really need is to find the value with minAge (O(log(N)), find the value with maxAge (O(log(N) again) and then the subset of values between them is your result

Comment: Well, I specifically need O(Log n), but I'm not sure what complexity my solution is.

Comment: @Jack 0 your current code scans all array elements from the start to get the 1st matche, then all the elements from the end to get the last match - thats O(N) because worst-case you'll scan through the entire collection. binary search skips to the middle of every range and then decides where to go from there

Comment: Your solution is O(n).  As an aside, you'll want to override ``hashCode`` if you are overriding ``equals``

Comment: Is it even possible to use Arrays.binarySearch to match the value from only getAge()? That's where I'm getting lost on how to use that method.

Comment: @radai I think that's all the answer OP should need :)

Comment: @Jack not as it is, but it is really easy to implement yourself or copy from existing code, like said

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get number of elements in a sorted array that fall within a certain range in log(n) time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242930/get-number-of-elements-in-a-sorted-array-that-fall-within-a-certain-range-in-log)

Answer (score 0):

Write a Comparator and sort the array using the comparator.

Then use the second binary search signature that takes a comparator with your new Comparator to find your upper and lower bounds.

Where you do not get an exact match, you will get a negative number, this indicates where your value would be if found, invert this and you have the location of the start/end of the values you do have that meet your boundary conditions.

Comment: I was unsure that it had already been sorted by the field we are using to identify boundary conditions.  If it has already been sorted by that field, don't sort, it would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This question is same to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242930/get-number-of-elements-in-a-sorted-array-that-fall-within-a-certain-range-in-log), where I gave the **O(logn)** implementation.

The idea is by range binary search for the lower bound and upper bound. For your example, all values are talking about **age** value.